# Android adding multiple lines to file internal stroage

Tags: java, android, io, fileoutputstream

I have a simple game app that has 3 place scoreboard and I need to save the data. I'm not sure whether I should be saving this on external or internal storage. I have managed to save a csv file in external but when testing I found it deosnt work on all devices. I am now looking at saving the data on internal storage and looking at the following standard file saving code.

```
String FILE_NAME = "file.txt";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(someText.toString().getBytes());
fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The class doesnt provide any nextLine() method.

My question is should I use external or internal storage, and if im using internal storage how can I seperate each line?

Comment: You are confusing at least three things here. Internal vs. external storage has no influence on how you write your data; `FileOutputStream` is for writing data, not reading, so there's no sensible way it could provide a `nextLine()` method.

Comment: Advice: Use `SharedProperties`. - If you don't want to do that, familiarize yourself with `FileOutputStream`, `FileInputStream`, `Writer`, `Reader`, `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader` for string (line) based file IO.

Comment: `FileInputStream` has exactly nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Writing:

```
String FILE_NAME = "file.txt";
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( fos ) );
    writer.println(someText.toString());
    writer.println(someOtherText.toString());
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Reading:

```
String FILE_NAME = "file.txt";
try {
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fis ) );
    String line;
    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
        System.out.println("Read line: " + line);
    } 
    reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for a simple wrapper to parse the data, cheers

Comment: There is no such method as `writeln()`.